# Is there any way not to implement interface methods in Java?

Tags: java

I don't want to make my class abstract for this. For e.g. I have class which want to implement 1 interface which has around 15-20 method declarations but only 4-5 methods are the ones which matter for my class.

Is there any other alternative to do this?

Comment: You can use default methods for your interface with 15-20, and so when you implement this interface only methods without default implementation are needed to be implemented, or make the implementing class an interface and offer those 4-5 methods a default implementation.

Comment: I don't know Your domain, but 15-20 methods seems quite big number. Change design

Comment: Delete the rest of the methods in the interface. Or use default methods

Comment: well, that's what interfaces are meant for: to define a behavior. Still, since `java-8` you can define `default` methods. But to me it looks like a design issue

Comment: Don't put so many methods in your interface.

Comment: If an interface has 15-20 methods, but only 4 or 5 are relevant, then that seems like bad design on the interface. Perhaps you should break it up.

Comment: You can leave the implementation empty. or return null, in case the method returns an object. But do this when you are really sure, those methods are of no need in the implementing class.

Comment: @boobalan *Always* throw exception in code branches you expect noone to call. If you just return null or do nothing, you'll have hard time debugging the problem when someone *does* call it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alternatives (to making your class abstract) are:

1. Supply default implementation to the interface methods you don't want to implement in your class within the interface itself (requires Java 8 or higher).

   For example:

   ```
   public interface YourInterface {
       ...
       default boolean someMethod () {
           return false;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Implement all the methods you don't want to implement with an empty body that throws an exception. This approach is common in the collections framework.

   For example:

   ```
   public class YourClass implements YourInterface {
       ...
       public boolean someMethod() {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

If possible, fix the underlying *design* issue.

If you can make a useful class that only implements 5 methods out of 20, that hints at the interface being in fact a mess of many independent contracts. Separate those independent contracts into separate interfaces and use whatever is needed, wherever is needed instead of having one huge interface that you only implement partially.

Comment: yes, this is the only answer that faces the base issue

Comment: @MarkoPacak Yet it still might be useless if the OP has no control over the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can have default methods, e.g.

```
interface Common {
    default void actionOne() {
        // nothing to do
    }
    // or
    default void actionTwo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Must be implemented if used");
    }
}
```

or you can have multiple interfaces and only implement the ones which matter.

Answer (score 0):

One option which other answers don't mention: you can do this by only creating the class at runtime, e.g. using [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

This should rarely be your first option, but it can be useful.